# Spring security filter is invoked twice with slightly different path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm following this [code sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login/src/main/java/example/RestConfig.java) and this [guide](https://www.toptal.com/spring/spring-security-tutorial) to implement a simple, stateless authentication for a REST API via Spring Boot + Security.

When firing a request to `/api/login`, I can see and trace that my controller method is properly invoked, the authentication is successful, and a token gets generated. However, the filter is then invoked a second time for `/api/api/login` which obviously fails and then fails the whole chain.

The controller method:

```java
@PutMapping("/api/login")
public LoginUserOutput loginUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginUserInput loginUserInput) {
    final var authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginUserInput.username(), loginUserInput.password()));
    final var user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();

    final var claims = JwtClaimsSet.builder().subject(user.getUsername()).build();
    final var header = JwsHeader.with(MacAlgorithm.HS256).build();
    final var token = jwtEncoder.encode(JwtEncoderParameters.from(header, claims));

    return new LoginUserOutput(token.getTokenValue());
}
```

And my security filter chain:

```java
@Bean
SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http.csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/prometheus/**").hasRole("MONITORING").and().httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new BearerTokenAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .accessDeniedHandler(new BearerTokenAccessDeniedHandler()))
            .build();
}
```

I've tried the endpoint both with Postman and the IntelliJ HTTP client.

This is the log output when running with Spring Security on DEBUG:

```
2023-05-08T21:18:42.121+02:00 DEBUG 32155 --- [io-28080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing PUT /api/login
2023-05-08T21:18:42.122+02:00 DEBUG 32155 --- [io-28080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-05-08T21:18:42.123+02:00 DEBUG 32155 --- [io-28080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured PUT /api/login
Hibernate: select u1_0.id,u1_0.hashed_password,u1_0.roles,u1_0.username from users u1_0 where u1_0.username=?
2023-05-08T21:18:42.234+02:00 DEBUG 32155 --- [io-28080-exec-3] o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    : Authenticated user
2023-05-08T21:18:42.235+02:00 DEBUG 32155 --- [io-28080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing PUT /api/api/login
```

Comment: The log is just by running the application or after hitting the controller?

Comment: It's after hitting the controller.

Comment: ok. can you add to the question the annotations you have on top of the class.

Comment: Have you added something like `@RequestMapping("api")` to the top of the class?